# in ReplacementSpan , when the text(content be drawn) is too long, and then the text is "... " why

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, draw, spannablestring

the follow code is PointReplaceSpan that want to draw blue circle in front of some text

```
    public class PointReplaceSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    private final String TAG = "PointReplaceSpan";
    private boolean DEBUG = true;
    private int mMeasureWidth;
    private int mPointColor = 0xB33FBEFF;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int textWidth;
    private Context mContext;
    private int radius;

    private final String ellipsis = "...";
    private boolean mIndicatorEnable;
    private int mPadding;
    private RectF textRectF;

    public PointReplaceSpan(Context context) {
        this(context, false);
    }

    public PointReplaceSpan(Context context, boolean pointIndicator) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mPaint = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        int color = 0x444444;
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        radius = dp2px(3);
        mIndicatorEnable = pointIndicator;
        textRectF = new RectF();
    }

    public void setPadding(int padding) {
        mPadding = padding;
    }

    public void setPointColor(int color) {
        mPointColor = color;
    }


    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
//get the width of text

        if (mIndicatorEnable) {
            mMeasureWidth = (int) mPaint.measureText(text, start, end) + 2 * radius + dp2px(4);
        } else {
            mMeasureWidth = (int) mPaint.measureText(text, start, end);
        }

        final int widthPixels = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        textWidth = (widthPixels - 2 * mPadding)/4;

        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "bankle getSize() called with text = [" + text + "], start = [" + start + "], end= "+end+" screenWidth "+widthPixels+" padding "+mPadding+" mMeasureWidth "+ mMeasureWidth+" textWidth "+ textWidth);
        }
        if (mMeasureWidth > textWidth) {
            return textWidth;
        }

        return mMeasureWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
//draw the text 
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            return;
        }
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "bankle draw() called with " + text +" [" + text + "], start = [" + start + "], end = [" + end + "], x = [" + x + "], top = [" + top + "], y = [" + y + "], bottom = [" + bottom +"]");
        }
        paint.setColor(mPointColor);
        Paint.FontMetrics fontM = paint.getFontMetrics();
        float v = top - (fontM.top - fontM.ascent / 2);
        y = (int) (top - fontM.ascent);

        int circlePointWidth = 0;
        if (mIndicatorEnable) {//draw point
            circlePointWidth = 2 * radius + dp2px(4);
            canvas.drawCircle(x + radius, v, radius, paint);
        }

        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "bankle draw() called with text = " + text + " mMeasureWidth " + mMeasureWidth + " textWidth " + textWidth);
        }

        if (mMeasureWidth > textWidth) {  // 文字过长时添加省略号
            float ellipsisWidth = mPaint.measureText(ellipsis, 0, ellipsis.length());
            float restWidth = textWidth - ellipsisWidth - circlePointWidth;

            int availableIndex = mPaint.breakText(text, 0, text.length(), true, restWidth, null);// available index of text should be drawn
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "bankle draw() called with text = ["+text+"] availableIndex "+ availableIndex +" text.length "+ text.length()+" ellipsisWidth "+ ellipsisWidth);
            }
            if (availableIndex > text.length() -1) {
                availableIndex = text.length() -1;
            }

            float measuredWidth = mPaint.measureText(text, 0, availableIndex);// the measureWidth of available text

            canvas.drawText(text, 0, availableIndex, x + circlePointWidth, y, mPaint);
            float ellipsisX = circlePointWidth + measuredWidth;// the margin x of ellipsis

            canvas.drawText(ellipsis, 0, ellipsis.length(), ellipsisX, y, mPaint);
            textRectF.set(x, top, x + circlePointWidth+ellipsisWidth+ measuredWidth, bottom);

        } else {
            canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + circlePointWidth, y, mPaint);
            float textWidth = mPaint.measureText(text, start, end);
            textRectF.set(x, top, x + circlePointWidth + textWidth, bottom);
        }

        if (DEBUG) {

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(textRectF, 10, 10, paint);
        }
    }

    private int dp2px(int dpValue) {
        return (int) mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * dpValue;
    }
}
```

in other place, i do this:

```
CharSequence appName = appInfo.getDisplayName(context)
    replace = new PointReplaceSpan(context, true);
    replace.setPadding(outPadding);
    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(appName);
    span.setSpan(replace,0,appName.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    holder.setAppName(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and then we can see below:

[image: android screenshot]

the logcat is :

---

```
bankle getSize() called with text = [SpreadScreenSpread], start = [0], end= 18 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 422 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Browser], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 154 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Google Play Store], start = [0], end= 17 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 332 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Gallery], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 128 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = […], start = [0], end= 18 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 58 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = […], start = [0], end= 18 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 58 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Browser], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 154 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Browser], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 154 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = […], start = [0], end= 17 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 28 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = […], start = [0], end= 17 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 28 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Gallery], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 128 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Gallery], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 128 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = […], start = [0], end= 18 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 58 textWidth 347
bankle draw() called with … […], start = [0], end = [18], x = [135.0], top = [0], y = [89], bottom = [112]
bankle draw() called with text = … mMeasureWidth 58 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Browser], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 154 textWidth 347
bankle draw() called with Browser [Browser], start = [0], end = [7], x = [87.0], top = [0], y = [89], bottom = [112]
bankle draw() called with text = Browser mMeasureWidth 154 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = […], start = [0], end= 17 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 28 textWidth 347
bankle draw() called with … […], start = [0], end = [17], x = [150.0], top = [0], y = [89], bottom = [112]
bankle draw() called with text = … mMeasureWidth 28 textWidth 347
bankle getSize() called with text = [Gallery], start = [0], end= 7 screenWidth 1440 padding 25 mMeasureWidth 128 textWidth 347
bankle draw() called with Gallery [Gallery], start = [0], end = [7], x = [100.0], top = [0], y = [89], bottom = [112]
bankle draw() called with text = Gallery mMeasureWidth 128 textWidth 347
```

when the width of text exceed the TextView, and then the text is assigned  to "..." as you see, why? anyone can help me any? please

additional,the correspond textview

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

finally I remove the attribue android:maxLines="1"
and then the problem has been solved bud I don't know why?

Comment: I have solved the problem by remove the attribute "android:ellipsize",but why?